# Quadratic residue modulo $p$ iff quadratic residue module $p^k$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime, $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $(a,p)=1$. I am trying to show that if $a$ is a square modulo $p$ then it is a square modulo $p^k$. I managed to prove this using an exponential function and finding explicitly the square root of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$, but it is rather long. Would someone have a simpler proof using the results of quadratic residues for odd primes?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Do you know that the group $\Bbb{Z}_{p^k}^*$ is cyclic?

Comment: No, but if I knew that, would there be a simple argument?

Answer (score 2):

Hensel's Lemma might be useful here. Use $x^2 - a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ as the polynomial equation and lift to $p^2$, $p^3$, ... (you can use induction to finish it off).

Since $f'(x) = 2x$, you're guaranteed that you can apply the lemma because if $X$ is a solution of the original equation, then $2X$ will never be divisible by $p$ because $a$ and $p$ are coprime.

Comment: In other words: if $x^2=a\pmod{p^k}$ one can find $y$ s.t. $(x+p^ky)^2=a\pmod{p^{k+1}}$ (it's actually very easy since $(x+p^ky)^2=x^2+2p^ky\pmod{p^{k+1}}$).

Comment: e.g. if $k=1$, write $x^2=a+pr$ and show that $r$ is divisible by 2 by looking at $x^2=a+pr \;(\text{mod }2)$ right? thank you

Comment: @Nre. Sorry, I'm a little confused by why you're considering mod 2. Are you familiar with Hensel's (lifting) lemma? The result you want follows immediately based on the Lemma and the polynomial I suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with the Lemma and hoped getting away without using it... I will have a precise look at it if there is no other easy solution :) and yes, my previous comment is wrong. Thanks